# Property 'request' does not exists on type 'void'

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I am new to Nodejs, and trying to create a SQL helper, without success. What am I doing wrong?

**db.ts:**

```
import sql from 'mssql/msnodesqlv8'
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
//import { config } from 'winston';

const config:sql.config =  {
    user:process.env.SQL_USER,
    password: process.env.SQL_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.SQL_DBNAME,
    server: process.env.SQL_URL!,
    port: +process.env.SQL_PORT!,
    options: {
        encrypt: false,
    },
  }

  const poolPromise = new sql.ConnectionPool(config)
  .connect()
  .then(pool => {
    console.log('Connected to MSSQL')
    return pool
  })
  .catch(err => console.log('Database Connection Failed! ', err))
export{ sql, poolPromise  }
```

**user.ts**

```
class UserDB {
    async login(username:string,password:string){
        try {
        
            const pool = await poolPromise
            const result = await pool.request()<--- error
            .input('username', sql.NVarChar, username)
            .input('password', sql.NVarChar, password)
            .execute('pwr_loginTenant');

            return  result.recordsets;
            
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('services:user.ts login error',error);
        }
    }
}
const userDB = new UserDB()
module.exports = userDB;
```

I am getting error on request:

> NODE JS - property 'request' does not exists on type 'void'

Comment: Have you tried `const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8')` instead? Be aware that [this driver](https://tediousjs.github.io/node-mssql/) requires Node.js v10 or later... and Windows. See the "Microsoft / Contributors Node V8 Driver for Node.js for SQL Server" notes on that link.

Comment: thx i am using node v16.13.0